# Can a System-App read the data of other apps on Android 9?

Tags: system-apps, file-permissions

I want to know if a system-app is able to read the data of other apps (the data stored in /data/data.) on Android 9.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to Android Entusiasts site, and while you are surfing on the site don't forget to check: https://android.stackexchange.com/tour for more details about questions and answers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes! **System Apps** with the protection level [signature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element) (the System APK must be signed with the same key used to sign the ROM/Firmware), can read/write/execute/delete all data stored on  **/data/data** or other folders on the device.

Note that third party apps (OEM custom apps) found on system/priv-app with protection level **signatureOrSystem** (Deprecated in Android 6.0). may not be able to do this unless they have **signature** protection level which means signed with the same key as the ROM/Firmware.

**Examples:** I've seen some chinese manufactures with their built-in data clone solutions which can make a backup to the whole APK and it's data in another phone, and IMO, this is a security risk which should not exist at all on android devices.

***EDIT 1:*** As i've mentioned before let's take a look at an Android APK which is able to copy other APKs data/data folders, it's called Amiclone "com.gionee.dataghost" from the Chinese smartphone manufacturer Gionee (which BTW, faced bankruptcy and liquidation on 2018)

- We have the following information, from version 2.1.0w_pub build 20100022

  - **Permissions:**

    ```
    android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    android.permission.ACCESS_MTK_MMHW
    android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
    android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER
    android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE            
    android.permission.BLUETOOTH
    android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
    android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
    android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
    android.permission.GET_TASKS
    android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
    android.permission.INTERNET
    android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
    android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
    android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
    android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS
    android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS
    android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
    android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
    android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    android.permission.READ_LOGS
    android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    android.permission.READ_SMS
    android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
    android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS
    android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
    android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
    android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
    android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE
    android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
    android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
    android.permission.WRITE_SMS
    com.gionee.youju.statistics.permission.READ_PROVIDER
    com.gionee.youju.statistics.permission.WRITE_PROVIDER
    ```
  - **Signature:**

    ```
    Number of signers: 1
    Signer #1 certificate DN: EMAILADDRESS=gionee@gionee.com, CN=Gionee, OU=Gionee, O=Gionee, L=ShenZhen, ST=GuangDong, C=CN
    Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: c2d992c8a4cda2eed55f69357d6759937878e9a0f0b629524e88aa81ed65f802
    Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 1bb8b4f46eafc2a06a46ba68fd8de543a5c65cbd
    Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: b49792a5687b641492e10a29152f7454
    Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
    Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
    Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 858b75200e11e0e62f6377b0b56beb728085823bddc31669d8348ee28b651815
    Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: c780dfb20637a7cedcaf78298ec1bfcb7b069da1
    Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: ceb817433cbe5a6a3c42cc7a562617ab
    ```

Also, this APK has a built-in busybox binary, and it's able to dump the whole user data from /data/data folders while transferring Apps from a Gionee device t o another.

## Conclusion:

Yes,  a system APK can copy other Apps and their data, but it's not only about signature as @Irfan has pointed out in his comment, there are permissions of different levels (some of them require signature level protection) etc...
But, as Android Enthusiasts replies are generally for end-users, the full details are not required to answer a question.

Comment: No they can't. It's not only about signatures.